# Android - Custom view not accepting long clicks

Tags: android, view

I'm trying to make my custom view to accept long clicks, but there is no way it works.

Any ideas please?

I've looked into others posts which had the similar issue but didn't find any solution.

Thanks,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.examples.danilofernandes.housemap.ViewForLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="100px"
    android:layout_height="100px" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="hello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/layout"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The view:

```
public class ViewForLayout extends View {

...

public ViewForLayout(final Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    setLongClickable(true);
    setOnLongClickListener(new MyLongClickListenerClass());

    ....

}

public class MyLongClickListenerClass implements OnLongClickListener{

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "I'm in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return true;

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
    public ViewForLayout(final Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        setLongClickable(true);
        setOnLongClickListener(new onLongClickListener(){

  @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "I'm in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return true;

    }

};);

        ....

}
```

(bracketing may be off I did it on the site)

Comment: I had a weird issue that was solved by this. I have something else to try. What happens if you system.out instead of toast in the onclick? You may be using the wrong context

Comment: I use this context on others methods and it looks fine

Comment: Is there anyreason you arent using the onclick tag in the xml?

Comment: I'm not looking for a click, I'm looking for a long click